# How is it possible that the band "Paradisio" was Belgian when they sang in Spanish?

Tags: history, pop, music-business, european

I have always thought that Paradisio, who made/performed the fantastic songs "[Baliando](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kKqsV3t94PY)" and "[Vamos a la Discoteca](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7uh50U-Xo0g)", was Spanish.

They sing in Spanish, look Spanish, and Belgium, from where they actually are, does not even have Spanish as an official language. (It's Dutch, French and German.)

Why would a Belgian band sing in (what appears to me to be) flawless Spanish? Why not in English if they were aiming for a European-wide or even world-wide audience?

Wouldn't picking Spanish severely limit themselves both in terms of their ability to sing it as well as the possible reach?

I guess regardless of the answer, I'm mostly annoyed that I've thought of them as "the most Spanish band of the 1990s" when they were not at all.

Comment: There are lots of reasons.  They may be Spanish immigrants, or born to Spanish parents.  They may have grown up in Spain (or a Spanish speaking country) and moved to Belgium later.  Or maybe they're really good at learning to speak Spanish phonetically. Or maybe they just like Spanish or like to perform songs that happen to be written in Spanish.

Answer (score 0):

Maria Isabel Garcia Asensio was born in Spain but I'm not sure about Patrick Samoy. For the most part, I just believe that they were both originally born and from Spain and moved to Belgium.